# Does date_trunc on current_date automatically pick date of current year in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT *
FROM public.business_calendar;
```

Above query gives me all data including year 2020 and 2021.

```
SELECT *
FROM public.business_calendar
WHERE  date_trunc('month', business_date) = date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) order by business_date
```

Above query gives me data of Jan 2021 and not Jan 2020. **Does date_trunc automatically work on current year when used with CURRENT_DATE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does date_trunc automatically work on current year when used with CURRENT_DATE?

Yes, `date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE)` will truncate the ***current date***.

You may be misunderstanding what [`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) does. `date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE)` does not return the month, it returns a complete timestamp at the start of the month. On January 17th, 2021 it will return `2021-01-01 00:00:00`.

If you want just the month use [`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

```
test=> select current_date;
 current_date 
--------------
 2021-01-17
(1 row)

test=> select date_trunc('month', current_date);
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2021-01-01 00:00:00-08
(1 row)

test=> select extract(month from current_date);
 date_part 
-----------
         1
(1 row)
```

If you want to match dates in the current month ignoring the year...

```
select *
from public.business_calendar
where extract(month from business_date) = extract(month from current_date)
order by business_date
```